# Doing something after for loop finishes in same function?

Tags: python, list, jython

Is this possible? I'm doing an bukkit plugin now (in Python, yes :D), and I'm forced to do this within one function, so I can't separate it and call it later... For example, if I have loop that loops through players on server and adds everyone except one player, I want it to finish, and then teleport i.e. "Player1" to random player. At the moment, it teleports "Player1" to random player every time because of for loop... I'll give you just little of code, since It looks messy in preview due to many things that are not involved in problem and could be confusable to you... Here it is:

```
listica = []
for p1 in org.bukkit.Bukkit.getWorld(nextvalue).getPlayers():
    if p1.getName() not in listica:
       try:
         listica.remove(event.getPlayer().getName())
         randomtarget = choice(listica)
         randomtargetreal = org.bukkit.Bukkit.getPlayer(randomtarget)
         event.getPlayer().teleport(randomtargetreal)
         event.getPlayer().sendMessage("%sYou teleported to: %s%s"%  (bukkit.ChatColor.GREEN, bukkit.ChatColor.DARK_GREEN, randomtarget))                                  
       except ValueError:
             randomtarget = choice(listica)
             randomtargetreal = org.bukkit.Bukkit.getPlayer(randomtarget)
             if event.getPlayer().getLocation() != randomtargetreal.getLocation():
             event.getPlayer().teleport(randomtargetreal)
             event.getPlayer().sendMessage("%sYou teleported to: %s%s"%(bukkit.ChatColor.GREEN, bukkit.ChatColor.DARK_GREEN, randomtarget))
```

What I want is:

```
run for loop:
when there is no more players to add a.k.a it finishes
do try loop
```

P.S. I can't do it in separate function.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
def func(args):
      for item in loop:
          do something
      try: # note indentation
          something else
```

Comment: Wow, I thought it will spit some indentation errors :O It looks like I missed something in docs, back to basics! :D Thank you very much! :)